# Building a chained Comparator via a List of Functions

Tags: generics, lambda, java-8, comparator

I was thinking about replacing some old comparator code, with something more modern.

```
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    if (null == o1 && null == o2)
        return 0;
    if (null == o1)
        return -1;
    if (null == o2)
        return 1;
    if (0 == o1.length() && 0 == o2.length())
        return 0;
    if (0 == o1.length())
        return -1;
    if (0 == o2.length())
        return 1;
    int result = Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length());
    if (0 != result)
        return result;
    result = Character.compare(o1.charAt(0), o2.charAt(0));
    if (0 != result)
        return result;
    return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```

I know about Java 8's Comparator methods, so the above can become:

```
Comparator<String> chained = Comparator.nullsFirst(
    Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).thenComparing(
        s -> s.length() == 0 ? -1 : s.charAt(0)).thenComparing(
        Function.identity());
```

But, it's a bit annoying that I need to write out `comparing` and `thenComparing` for each comparison. Ideally, I'd just pass in a List or multiple lambdas.

Something like:

```
Comparator.comparing(
    String::length, 
    s -> s.length() == 0 ? 0 : s.charAt(0), 
    Function.identity());
```

The following is the closest I've gotten, with some commented sections to indicate what isn't valid due to Generics not matching. The sticking point seems to be that I want to pass in multiple `Function<T, ?>` with the wildcard not being pinned to a single capture. I'm guessing that's not possible.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class MultiComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {
    private Comparator<T> comparator;

    public MultiComparator() {
        this.comparator = Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(o -> 0));
    }

    /*
    public MultiComparator(List<Function<T, ? extends Comparable<?>>> extractors) {
        this();
        extractors.stream().forEach(this::add);
    }

    public MultiComparator(Function<T, ? extends Comparable<?>>... extractors) {
        this(Arrays.asList(extractors));
    }
    */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("1", "11", "111", "2", "22", "222", "3", "123", "432", "aaa", "1234",
                "", "", null, null, null);

        MultiComparator<String> multi = new MultiComparator<>();

        multi.add(String::length);
        multi.add(s -> s.length() == 0 ? 0 : s.charAt(0));
        multi.add(Function.identity());

        Collections.shuffle(strings);
        Collections.sort(strings, multi);
        System.err.println(strings);

        /*
        multi = new MultiComparator<>(String::length, s -> s.length() == 0 ? -1 : s.charAt(0));

        Collections.shuffle(strings);
        Collections.sort(strings, multi);
        System.err.println(strings);
        */

        Comparator<String> chained = Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)).thenComparing(s
                -> s.length() == 0 ? -1 : s.charAt(0)).thenComparing(Function.identity());

        Collections.shuffle(strings);
        Collections.sort(strings, chained);
        System.err.println(strings);

        Collections.shuffle(strings);
        Collections.sort(strings, (o1, o2) -> {
            if (null == o1 && null == o2) return 0;
            if (null == o1) return -1;
            if (null == o2) return 1;
            if (0 == o1.length() && 0 == o2.length()) return 0;
            if (0 == o1.length()) return -1;
            if (0 == o2.length()) return 1;
            int result = Integer.compare(o1.length(), o2.length());
            if (0 != result) return result;
            result = Character.compare(o1.charAt(0), o2.charAt(0));
            if (0 != result) return result;
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        });
        System.err.println(strings);
    }

    public <U extends Comparable<U>> void add(Function<T, U> fieldExtractor) {
        this.comparator = this.comparator.thenComparing(Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(fieldExtractor)));
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        return this.comparator.compare(o1, o2);
    }
}
```

On the plus side, I can just use thenComparing without having to write my own utility class.

---

---

Thanks to the solution by Tagir Valeev, in the end I dropped the custom Comparator class and just have two methods to return a new Comparator.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Comparator<T> create(List<Function<T, ? extends Comparable<?>>> extractors) {
    return extractors.stream().map(e -> Comparator.comparing((Function<T, Comparable<Object>>) e)).reduce
            (Comparator::thenComparing).orElse(Comparator.comparing(o -> 0));
}

@SafeVarargs
public static <T> Comparator<T> create(Function<T, ? extends Comparable<?>>... extractors) {
    return create(Arrays.asList(extractors));
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible to solve, but unchecked cast is necessary. First declare the `add` in the following way:

```
public <U extends Comparable<? super U>> void add(Function<T, U> fieldExtractor) {
    this.comparator = this.comparator.thenComparing(
                           Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.comparing(fieldExtractor)));
}
```

I replaced `U extends Comparable<U>` with `U extends Comparable<? super U>`. This is perfectly normal. Now constructors:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public MultiComparator(List<Function<T, ? extends Comparable<?>>> extractors) {
    this();
    extractors.stream().forEach(e -> this.add((Function<T, Comparable<Object>>)e));
}

@SafeVarargs
public MultiComparator(Function<T, ? extends Comparable<?>>... extractors) {
    this(Arrays.asList(extractors));
}
```

Now your code works and does not even produce warnings:

```
multi = new MultiComparator<>(String::length, s -> s.length() == 0 ? -1 : s.charAt(0));
```

Comment: Of course! Not sure why I didn't think of casting. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I don’t think that saving the few letters `thenComparing` deserves writing any bit of extra code. You are even loosing performance with the generic solution as you can’t use `comparingInt` etc., thus have to live with unnecessary boxing overhead.

Instead of writing utility methods, you should better spent time thinking about what you are actually comparing:

```
Comparator<String> chained = Comparator.nullsFirst(
  Comparator.comparingInt(String::length))
    .thenComparing(s -> s.length() == 0 ? -1 : s.charAt(0))
    .thenComparing(Function.identity());
```

First, you are comparing the string by length and only if their lengths differ, your comparator resorts to the other comparators. The second one will compare the first character which is an obsolete operation as the third comparator will compare the strings character by character *starting with the first one*.

It might look like something special due to the special handling of empty strings, but lets look at the possible scenarios:

- Both strings are empty; in this case the followup comparators are obsolete as they will all have the same result, two empty strings are always equal. The 3rd comparator would be sufficient
- Only one string is empty; in this case neither the second nor the third comparator will get called, as strings of different length are already considered unequal by the first, length based comparator
- Neither is empty; in this case, as already said, the second comparator is obsolete as the 3rd one will compare the first character anyway

So you see, in all cases the second comparator is obsolete—so let’s look at the 3rd one: `.thenComparing(Function.identity());` is a disguise as `identity()` is not a real property. It makes the chain look like there were three properties to compare but actually, it is delegating to the ordinary string comparison, aka *natural order* of the `String` class.

For the natural order, we don’t need to create a comparator, we can use the [existing one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--).

So the resulting comparator is:

```
Comparator<String> chained = Comparator.nullsFirst(
    Comparator.comparingInt(String::length).thenComparing(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
```

or, using `import static java.util.Comparator.*;`:

```
Comparator<String> chained = nullsFirst(
    comparingInt(String::length).thenComparing(naturalOrder()));
```

This doesn’t look worse than code utilizing your generic static factory method, but what’s more interesting, neither comparator actually fits into the factory method’s pattern. You have to make compromises at each comparator, like using boxing on every string length to compare and obfuscating a natural order as `identity()` property comparator, to make the factory work. And all that for saving a few characters…

Comment: Fair enough and entirely valid; certainly in this case. I'd argue that it's still a fun exercise and in other situations a similar pattern may be useful. I do appreciate your input.

Comment: I have no problem with “fun exercises” (and the existence of multiple answers to a question). But I think for real life cases, there are too often comparators not fitting into this pattern and then, using such a method for the remaining cases where it fits, creates inconsistent code. But that’s just me… I also admit, there would be no problem had the developers named the method(s) `then` rather than `thenComparing`…